# How to make the html title change in javascript

Tags: javascript

I did something like this

```
<head>
<script src="trans.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title><script>trans("Configuration: Status - Software")</script></title>
</head>
```

However the web title looks like

trans("Configuration: Status - Software")

Why is the js not working here,What should  modify to make it work?

Here's what tran.js look like

```
function trans(key)
{
  document.write(getkey(key));
}
function getkey(key)
{
   var text;
   text = lang_pack[key];

   if (text == undefined || text == "")
   {

      text = key;


   }
   return(text);
}
```

Comment: the <script> disappeared when I post it ?

Comment: using either JS or jquery setup the document.load function and set it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use a script inside of a title tag -- can you move it into a different block?

It's unclear exactly what trans.js is, but you can try:

```
<script>
    document.title = trans('Configuration: Status -Software');
</script>
```

Comment: It just return another string.

Comment: @JohnnyChen Then yeah, you should be good with moving it into a different block (preferably into a different file, for unobtrusive Javascript).

Answer (score 1):

You should try setting the title in javascript like

```
 document.title = trans('Configuration: Status - Software');
```

Comment: I am thinking the OP wants to set the title as the result of the function `trans`

Comment: @user2310289 this answer is still correct, we just don't know what's in function trans, and the answer can be easily modified by the OP. we don't have to do *everything* for them

Comment: New answer is completely different and is now valid.

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("title").innerHTML;

 temp[0].innerHTML = "your new title";
```

Comment: You can get element by tag name "title" and change html of that element thats it..

Answer (score 0):

Try including the src in the same script tag as the function call:

`<head>
<script src="trans.js" type="text/javascript">trans("Configuration: Status - Software")</script></title>
</head>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<head>
  <script src="trans.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title></title>
  <script>document.title = getkey("Configuration: Status - Software")</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
<head>
   <title>This is Test 1st</title>
   <script>
      var field = "This is Test 2nd";
      $("title").append(field);
   </script>
</head>
```

you need is a [jquery](http://jquery.com/) library.